# Migration DB postgresql in windows to Red Hat(linux)

Tags: postgresql, migration

I would like to know how I could migrate a postgresql database which is currently in a Windows operating system to Red Hat? I'm a beginner and I don't know where to start.

Thanks .

Comment: pg_dump and pg_restore: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup.html

Comment: Make sure you use `pg_dumpall` from the later PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pg_dump will create a file with the queries that are needed to recreate the state of your database. The file will look like a transaction or write ahead log.

```
pg_dump databasename > dumpfilename
```

pg_restore then will use this file to recreate your database.
It's also useful to migrate to a newer database version

you could also use

```
psql newdatabasename < dumpfilename
```